# Getting ActiveRecord Query to work with a left outer join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong syntactically here, would appreciate help. An `InventoryItem` has many `MaintenanceOrders`. Each `MaintenanceOrder` has a boolean field that is `still_usable`. Logically, I want to run a query for all `InventoryItems` that are still usable, meaning they EITHER don't have any `MaintenanceOrders` at all, OR that none of their `MaintenanceOrders` have a flag of `still_usable: false`.

Quick Rspec

```
describe "test query" do
 before do
   InventoryItem.create(random_id:"a")
   InventoryItem.create(random_id:"b")
   InventoryItem.create(random_id:"c")

   InventoryItem.where(random_id:"a").last.maintenance_orders.create(still_usable:false)
   InventoryItem.where(random_id:"b").last.maintenance_orders.create(still_usable:nil)
   InventoryItem.where(random_id:"b").last.maintenance_orders.create(still_usable:true)


   @query = InventoryItem.left_outer_joins(:maintenance_orders).where.not(maintenance_orders:{still_rentable:false}).distinct
 end
 it "should return b & c" do
   expect(@query.map(&:random_id)).to match_array(["b","c"])
   # a has a maintenance order with flag still_usable:false so is excluded
   # b has maintenance orders, but none have flag still_usable:false, so is included
   # c has no maintenance orders, so is included
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using SQL `NOT EXISTS`

```sql
InventoryItem.where("NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM maintenance_orders 
   WHERE (maintenance_orders.inventory_item_id = inventory_items.id) 
   AND maintenance_orders.still_rentable = false)")
```

Comment: this worked! i'm curious can this be done with the syntax provided by ActiveRecord or does SQL have to be used? like i'm still curious why my code was syntatically wrong and didn't work

Comment: I dont think there is any syntax provided by `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: Also what is the field name is it `still_rentable` or `still_usable`?

Comment: I you want to write query rails way,  You can also use `NOT IN` with subquery - `InventoryItem.where.not(id: MaintenanceOrder.where(still_usable: false).select(:inventory_item_id))`

Comment: Ah ok so writing it still requires another DB query into MaintenanceOrder, ok thanks!

Comment: It will execute only one query and not two. refer - [Rails ActiveRecord Subqueries](https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/23/rails-activerecord-subqueries/)